# ORA-08243: recursive audit operation attempted

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit-trail

I have the following error coming up very often: ORA-08243: recursive audit operation attempted. I am running Standard edition 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit on Linux.

Any ideas on what is causing this? Any help is much appreciated.

My audit tablespace is unlimited size and is bigfile. Autoextend is on next 500M.
Here is a snapshot of the tablespace which has SYS.AUD$.

```
NAME                              MB_ALLOCATED       USED       FREE   PCT_USED   MAX_SIZE 
--------------------------------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
*a AUDIT_TRAIL                           71640 70526.8125  1113.1875  .10509314   67108864
```

Here is an extract from the trace file.

```
*********START PLSQL RUNTIME DUMP************
***Got internal error Exception caught in pl/sql run-time while running PLSQL***
***Got ORA-8243 while running PLSQL***
ANONYMOUS BLOCK:
library unit=25e6870b8 line=8 opcode=99 static link=0 scope=0
FP=7ffff5dac028 PC=25295b052 Page=0 AP=0 ST=7ffff5dac3f0
DL0=7ffff5c54270 GF=7ffff5c54318 DL1=7ffff5c542b8 DPF=7ffff5c54308 DS=25295b458
   DON library unit variable list instantiation
------ ------------ ------------- -------------
     0    25e6870b8  7ffff5c54318  7ffff5c58678
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
   scope    frame
-------- --------
       2        0
       1 7ffff5dac028
package variable  address     size
---------------- -------- --------
               0 7ffff5c54320      368
version=43123476 instantiation size=536
exception     id error    DON offset  begin    end    DID
--------- ------ ----- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
        0      0     0     11    166     20    165
        1      0     0      1    228     20    165
    line pcode offset
-------- ------------
       1            2
       1           14
       8           20
      10           50
      12           52
      15           64
      17          160
      20          166
      21          166
      28          224
      28          226
      26          228
      27          228
      28          230
***********END PLSQL RUNTIME DUMP************
kdpurtab: err=604 goc1=604 goc2=8243 goc3=8243
```

Comment: This error occur in many case like in profile management if there less logical_reads_per_call..so there will be another error along with this error so please check that error also